# How do you measure performance/success of web based applications?

Tags: web-app, response-time, business-application, indicator, analytics

When I find/read articles about analytics and especially setting KPIs, they're always about websites & web shops. As I'm now more into web based (business) applications including mobile versions (apps), I'm wondering if there also exist terms that are equivalent to "KPIs" in the application world. How does one usually measure performance/success? Are there standards? And which software is used here in order to measure success?

Would be nice to hear how you handle this and maybe you know some web resources?

Comment: My favourite measure is the dollar/pound. What are you trying to measure, exactly?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollarpounds

Comment: ;) thanks for your question. for example: we work on a web based business application handling vouchers on a very large (global) scale. though there are working many experienced people (programmers, client support, ...) on this project for years the application and it's results were never tracked in detail (e.g. whats the user journey.. how do users handle the voucher process exactly,...). Of course we have client feedback and stuff but i think thats not really enough to ensure a good ux and helping to make the application perform even better (business perspective).

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question it is important to define broad words such as 'success' or 'performance' within the context of the specific application. Key performance indicator is itself a very broad term, with defined sets of KPIs specific to each business and application.

You have to be really clear and careful about what you want to measure then use tools like analytics, tracking, data mining etc. to measure those things. By think carefully I mean qualify the value of a certain measurement outcome, for example is an average short visit time good or bad? Users might actually be very successful at finding what they want, so is a long time on the site really that good?

With e-commerce you will likely be looking at the bottom line: is a satisfactory return on promotion investment being made and the site making a profit? For most applications repeat use is a good indicator of success but most measures will be specific to the case in point.

Talk to your stake-holders and engage your early adopters and this will help you focus on what to measure.